# TCP Client/Server with two dimensonal parity bit c++

Tags: c++, tcp, boost-asio, parity

I got a problem there with which you can hopefully help me.
I need to programm a TCP Client and Server using asio http://think-async.com/ and streambased in-output. However I also need to error check using two dimensional parity bits (DATA,ACK,NAK) and I have no single idea how to do this.

Hopefully you can help me.

Comment: Start with something simple like "Send number - Receive character"  client-server application. Once you'll get into trouble, post a concrete question.

Comment: I have no problem with programming the client /server application. My problem is that I don't know how to error check with two dimensional parity bits.

Comment: You dont need this. TCP stream cannot be delivered corrupted since it have few levels of CRC checking.

Comment: TCP doesnt need it, ok i got this. However, I have to check it since i have to produce errors randomly in the stream. So the question is: How do i add random errors in the stream and how do i check for them?